# captcha or not?

Tags: php, security, post, captcha

i hate captcha, do you think there is a better solution

Comment: There are some answers here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940887/need-alternatives-to-captcha. However, +1 for "I hate captcha".

Comment: Same for me: I also hate capchas. Some weeks ago I had to set up a gmail account. I didn't manage to enter the captcha correctly. I tried the audio one and that was even worse. Two friends and I got it working after a couple of tries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check [Practical non-image based CAPTCHA approaches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472/practical-non-image-based-captcha-approaches)

I asked a question earlier [Need suggestions/ideas for easy-to-use but secure captchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356337/need-suggestions-ideas-for-easy-to-use-but-secure-captchas)

However if you are irritated due to the difficulty faced by users because of the very existence of captchas, then there has been a lot of debate over this and people are still trying hard to come up with a universal solution which can work even for very popular sites.

You should see http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html for implementation of [Negative captchas](http://damienkatz.net/2007/01/negative_captch.html). But sadly, this is not effective as yet for site specific spam attacks (when your site gets very popular) as far as I have understood. The author says he has been using these techniques successfully for less popular sites. The overall conclusion with the state-of-the-art negative captchas is that whatever technique you use, spammers can program their bots to crack it in some time *if they target your site*. And they will probably target your site when it gets very popular. But you can definitely use them till your site is not very popular.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematical questions are becoming increasingly popular

*e.g. : what is 3 + 2?*

These are often easier to read than captchas which can be very confusing for some users.

Comment: why in gods name a down vote. This is a valid answer and you see a lot of sites deploy this. You got my vote of approval!

Comment: Thank you @Alfred, I was a little miffed when this got voted down with no reason given.

Comment: Maybe because this method is not bulletproof, but then again I think it will stop a lot of spam! Even captcha's aren't bulletproof!

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is a captcha. What's the difference, really, between saying 'type this word' and 'type this number'? You could use any kind of common knowledge question here - random example, "what animal goes 'woof'?" or even, 'what text can you see in this image"...

Comment: For me, the difference is that a mathematical question is much easier to read and is a good alternative to a 'traditional' capcha where the text is very scrambled and for which there are 1000s of bots out there that are designed to crack them.  In time, these will also become unsuitable as they will become less reliable as bots become more sophisticated, but I think that they are a good solution at the moment.

Comment: -1 It doesn't matter that this is a different type of Turing test it is still a Turing test. The only difference is that this one is trivial to break.  This is not a secure system,  this is a clear and blatant vulnerability and deserves many -1's.

Answer (score 4):

I have a a bogus form input (something like zip, or any other info that bots love to fill out but you really don't need) that has `visibility: hidden; position: absolute`. The motivation behind this is to get an input that is invisible to the user, but visible to the bot. So, whenever you get a request where that specific input is filled out, you know that it wasn't a human.

I use `visibility: hidden; position: absolute` so that it still uses up space, but doesn't clutter the design. This is for the bots that use more elaborate techniques to detect hidden inputs since, for JS, something isn't hidden if it takes up any amount space.

I haven't tested this technique on largely successful site as of yet, but it is still worth a try. Beware however that some Browsers (I am looking at you Safari/OSX!) that take info from your contact list and fills out all the input fields automatically (potentially even your hidden inputs) for you so you better check for bugs in that direction.

Comment: it's the honeypot method, it's a good one, well known and excellent.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this in a cute way a couple of years ago.

I had an "email me" form on a small business website that I wanted to be maximally accessible; spam bots found it and started overwhelming the legitimate messages.  From reading the server logs, I learned that bots were submitting the form without re-fetching it first -- somebody had cached my form and was simply sending a POST whenever they had some garbage for me to read.  A hidden form input would help for a few days, but then some bot's owner would figure out the right input, cache it, and the deluge would begin again.

I didn't have any backend where I could add session information to the form, and didn't want to add any.  Instead, between the "Type your message here" box and the hidden element, I inserted the output of a script that writes

> `<!-- instructions for spam robots: we are a waste of your money, go away, thanks -->
>
> <div class="float-left" style="font-size: x-small;"> 
>
> There will be a short delay before you may submit the form.  If you 
>
> have been typing in your information, the delay may already have 
>
> ended. 
>
> <br/><span>
>
> 4 ... 
>
> </span><span>
>
> <!--
>
> d92cbd14985295ac27929a6db7891a90ec4173a8358dcadab134cc589ce2de54 
>
> 1468365bd33b520754ddb8223252e7e6e7584ddb956ef1bb28628e27cfea86c6 
>
> -->`

The garbage block is randomly generated to make it hard to compress.  I experimented with how long the blocks of garbage needed to be.  When I got the form size up to about 200K, the spam messages stopped.

This is actually not a lot of extra data, about like adding a few extra images to the page.  Even for a hypothetical customer on dialup, the delay between rendering the text box and rendering the submit button is shorter than the time it would probably take to actually compose a message.

Comment: Interesting. First time I've seen this suggested.

Answer (score 2):

there is a nice trick which you can use by setting an empty input `displayed none` to the user but visible to the bot.

and if that input filed `!==""` empty, return false for the form.

there is more here http://klauskjeldsen.dk/avoid-html-form-spam-using-css/

Answer (score 1):

if you hate captcha then I can give youe two quick other options:

- any kind of [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login)(facebook connect you almost know for certain the user is trustworthy).
- [akismet](http://akismet.com/)